# My program shows an error, It says that a semicolon missing

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Fact
```

> program to find factorial numbers

```
{
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int n;
     Fact()
```

> an empty constructor

```
     {
        }

void accept()
    {
           System.out.println("Enter the number");
           n=sc.nextInt();
           System.out.println(pact(n));
        }
   **int pact(int n)**
```

> here is where my program says that it is missing a semicolon

```
  (
           if(n==1)
              return 1;
           else
              return n*fact(n-1);
   }     
   public static void main()
{
Fact obj=new Fact();
obj.accept();
}
}
```

Comment: it´s quite hard to tell without having a properly formatted class as a whole here.

Comment: With this bad formatting, the one thing I can notice is the missing `String[] args` as the arguments of the main method.

Comment: Try an IDE like JetBrains instead of text editor, it will helps you a lot, especially avoid syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that

```
int pact(int n)
(
```

should be

```
int pact(int n)
{
```

You have `String args[]` missing as the arguments in the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Removed invalid language constructs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fact {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;

Fact() {
}

void accept() {
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(fact(n));
}

int fact(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fact obj = new Fact();
    obj.accept();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After return statement you used closed curly, and no open curly is there .
You started with open parenthesis and closed with curly.
Just change that.

Comment: And you should mention the error in main method header.

Answer (score 2):

If you copied the code correctly, you need to use a { instead of ( in this part of the code.

```
  (
       if(n==1)
          return 1;
       else
          return n*fact(n-1);
  }
```

> so it should be

```
  {
       if(n==1)
          return 1;
       else
          return n*fact(n-1);
  }
```